# Pinning Vertex group in cloth physics removes wrinkles

Tags: mesh, physics, cloth-simulation, vertex-groups

I created a bag of chips, added a cloth physics to it, and added pressure so it inflates.

I had created a Vertex group at the top and bottom of the bag so I can pin it in the cloth physics properties.

When the bag inflates (a typical product bag should have wrinkles and deformities on the sides), it smoothen out and doesn't show any form of wrinkles.

Upon removing the pinned Vertex group, the bag inflates and and the wrinkles on the sides are visible.

I don't know why pinning a Vertex group makes such difference, but is there a way I can retain the wrinkles and deformities even with the pinned Vertex group?

[image]

[image]